# spaCy lemmatizer help deciphering generic error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, spacy

I'm trying to create a new pandas df column to hold the lemmatized text from a column of tokenized text using:

```
df['new_col'] = [tok for token in col:
        lemmas.append(tok.lemma_.lower().strip() if tok.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else tok.lower_)]
```

But I'm getting this generic syntax error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-19-825d2d6e40ee>", line 1
    df['new_col'] = [tok for token in col:
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've googled around to find more appropriate syntax without much luck.  I'm new to Python, and it's a challenge to really figure out what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're combining the for-loop syntax `for x in iterable:` with the list comprehension syntax `[x for x in iterable]`. The only times I've seen colons inside list comprehensions has been in lambda functions (e.g., `[lambda x: x*x for x in range(10)]`). Here, the colon shows up without a lambda expression, so the interpreter chokes.

Hopefully this is what you're looking for:

```py
df['new_col'] = [tok.lemma_.lower().strip() if tok.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else tok.lower_ for tok in col]
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried your code, but got a different error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lemma_'`

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Try `for tok in col` instead of `for token in col`.

Comment: hmm... I've never actually used SpaCy, but it seems that the `col` column contains strings, not SpaCy tokens!

Comment: My tokenizer code didn't return any errors, and looks to have processed fine but I'll go back and check it out.

Comment: Ok - I went back and made sure my tokenizer was working properly but now am getting a different error using your code `AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'lemma_'`.  To me this reads like spacy.tokens.doc.Doc can't lemmatize - but I don't really know where to go from here.